# dialog button not working

Tags: android, dialog

I have post about this before but iv had no luck. this is my code that i have at the moment. what i am looking for is. My button on my dialog to simply go back (or close) to the origanl
screen. i have been reading about the back button in android and it just go's over my head.

java.code

```
import my.dlog.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class DlogActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Dialog dialog;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main2);
dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
dialog.setCancelable(true);
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DlogActivity.this, DlogActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
  }

  public void onClick(View v) {
    dialog.show();
  }
});

 }
}
```

xml.code

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:onClick="DlogActivity"/>




  <ImageView
  android:layout_width="236dp"
  android:layout_height="220dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="100dp" android:background="@drawable/carsee"/>


  <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is totally confusing to me.  I suspect that you might be confused about the difference between an activity and a dialog.  If all you are trying to do is show a dialog on top of your activity, and then return to that activity when the dialog is dismissed, you need dialog.dismiss().  Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

If you are trying to achieve something else, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't connecting your button correctly.  You look for id of button1 in Java

```
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

but in the xml, you assign the button an id of btn2

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    .
    android:onClick="DlogActivity"/>
```

Make sure these id's match.

Comment: i am trying to just close the dailog screen. i think i just got a bit lost. but i think i will start agian with alertdialog it sound like what am after. a button.textview and imageview.thank you for your comments